# Is there any way in python scripting that can be used to save the top best 5 models generated?

Tags: python

I am working on QSPR modelling of using machine learning approaches , while doing so I am using a loop for testing various combinations of train test data so as to get a split with the best accuracy.
while doing so I got 6 models with accuracy more than 0.8 hence I now want to save those top 5 models separately so I can use the models to evaluate the models for validation metrics and select the best one .

```
best = 0.8
for _ in range(10000):
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)
 rf = RandomForestRegressor()
rf.fit(x_train, y_train)
acc = rf.score(x_test, y_test)
if acc > best:
    best = acc
    print("Accuracy: " + str(acc))
    with open("qsar01.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(rf, f)

  output -
           Accuracy: 0.8122869479449127
           Accuracy: 0.8366981056576208
           Accuracy: 0.8393107397410712
           Accuracy: 0.8622239028780015
           Accuracy: 0.8951618881018277
           Accuracy: 0.8957666485504531
```

but the code saves only model with best accuracy . can anyone suggest what modifications can i make to save the top 5 models.

Comment: Change `qsar01.pickle` for each iteration, such as `for i in range(10000): ... open("qsar" + str(i) + ".pickle")`

Answer (score 0):

you could keep a list of the best 5 something like:

```
best5 = []

# create some example data (a tuple of the acc and model you want to save)
for i in range(10, 0, -1):
    acc, rf = i, None
    best5.append((acc, rf))

# sort best5 by best acc
best5.sort(key=lambda x:-x[0])

# trim list to 5 entries
best5 = best5[:5]
```

then write out the list in your pickle statement. you could also check if acc is better than the last entry in your list before writing your file, so something like:

```
if len(best5) < 5 or acc >= best5[-1]:
    # update list
    pass
```